# Android xmlSerializer throws IllegalStateExecption

Tags: android, xml, serialization

I am using the xmlSerializer api to create an xml file that exports data from my db. The code is shown below. I am using xmlSerializer because I am working with min API level 7.

```
        private String extractFromDB() throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalStateException, IOException {


    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
    // start DOCUMENT
    xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);

    // open tag: <root>
    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "root");
    Cursor c = DB.getMembers();

    while (c.getPosition() < c.getCount()) {
        // open tag: <member>
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "member");

        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "GR_ID", "" + c.getInt(1));

        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "email", "" + c.getInt(2));

        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "first_name", c.getString(3));

        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "last_name", "" + c.getString(4));

        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "account_nr", "" + c.getInt(5));

        xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "balance", "" + c.getDouble(6));

    }
    // end DOCUMENT
    xmlSerializer.endDocument();
    return writer.toString();
}
```

The second startTag() throws an illegalstateexeption.

```
    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "member");
```

Does anyone has an idea on what might be causing this error

Comment: are you sure is in this line  xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "member");... can you post your logcat

Comment: You're right, it was not the startTag().

Comment: maybe is this line:  xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "first_name", c.getString(3)); you need to add the ""+ to the last parameter